# Batch RPG Game with Login Function

Tags: authentication, batch-file

I'm creating a D&D style RPG game using batch files and I saw another person using a login feature that creates a batch file that returns you to where you left off. so I tried to replicate it. Almost everything works except for the fact that it won't create the batch file to allow you to go back. When you go through the process of creating a login it goes through it like normal and on the next screen under start even displays that your username is what you set it as but it won't create the batch file. Some of the code might be scattered because I'm still learning and some of it unfinished but this is what I have so far.

```
title Lost Mine of Phandelvor
@echo off
:entergame
cls
echo.
echo Welcome to Lost Mine of Phandelvor
echo -------------------
echo.
echo 1. Create Account
echo 2. Login
echo 3. Exit
echo.
set /p input=

if %input% EQU 1 goto createuser
if %input% EQU 2 goto login
if %input% EQU 3 exit
if %input% GEQ 4 goto entergame

:createuser
cls
echo.
echo What would you like your Username to be?
set /p username1= 
set v1f=0
goto checkforspaces

:checkforspaces
set x=!v1f!
set Letter%v1f%=!username1:~%x%,1!
if "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU " " (
echo.
echo.
echo Sorry you can't use spaces in your Username.
pause>nul
goto entergame
)
if NOT "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU "" (
set /a v1f=%v1f%+1
)
echo.
echo What would you like your Password to be?
set /p password1= 
goto DATA_VALUES

:login
cls
set /p name=Username: 
if not exist "%name%.bat" (
echo That is not a valid Username.
pause>nul
goto entergame
)
set /p pass1=Password: 
call %name1%.bat
if not %password1% EQU %pass1% (
echo That is not a valid Password.
pause>nul
goto entergame
)
goto create

:DATA_FILES
set lvl1=1
set exp1=0
set expmax1=300
set gp1=10
set hp1=12
set ac1=15
set profbonus1=2
set str1=4
set dex1=1
set con1=2
set int1=0
set wis1=2
set cha1=2
set destination=SAVE_GAME_FILES
set destination2=SAVE_GAME_FILES
goto SAVE_GAME_FILES

:SAVE_GAME_FILES
(
echo set username1=%username1%
echo set password1=%password1%
:DATA_VALUES
echo set lvl1=%lvl1%
echo set exp1=%exp1%
echo set expmax1=%expmax1%
echo set gp1=%gp1%
echo set hp1=%hp1%
echo set ac1=%ac1%
echo set profbonus1=%profbonus1%
echo set str1=%str1%
echo set dex1=%dex1%
echo set con1=%con1%
echo set int1=%int1%
echo set wis1=%wis1%
echo set cha1=%cha1%
echo set destination=%destination%
echo set destination2=%destination2%
)>%username1%.bat
goto start

:start
cls
echo.
echo Currently logged in as %username1%
echo.
echo Welcome to my fantasy style role playing game.
echo You will need to create a character.
echo.
echo Enjoy!
echo.
echo 1. Continue to Character Selection
echo 2. Exit
echo.
set /p input=

if %input% EQU 1 goto create
if %input% EQU 2 exit
if %input% GEQ 3 goto start

:create
cls
echo.
echo Welcome to Character Creation
echo.
echo Pick your race!
echo.
echo 1. Human
echo 2. Dwarf
echo 3. Elf
echo 4. Dragonborn
echo 5. Tiefling
echo.
set /p input=Choice:
if %input%==1 goto createHuman
if %input%==2 goto createDwarf
if %input%==3 goto createElf
if %input%==4 goto createDragonborn
if %input%==5 goto createTiefling
goto create

:createHuman
cls
echo.
echo You have chosen Human as your race!
echo.
echo Choose your class
echo.
echo 1. Fighter
echo 2. Ranger
echo 3. Rogue
echo 4. Wizard
echo.
set /p input=Choise
if %input%==1 goto humanFighter
if %input%==2 goto humanRanger
if %input%==3 goto humanRogue
if %input%==4 goto humanWizard
goto createHuman

:humanFighter
cls
echo.
echo You have chosen Fighter as your class!
echo.
echo Choose your weapon
echo.
echo 1. Battleaxe 1D8 Slashing
echo 2. Longsword 1D8 Slashing
echo 3. Rapier 1D8 Piercing
echo.
set /p input=choise
if %input%==1 goto humanFighter1
if %input%==2 goto humanFighter2
if %input%==3 goto humanFighter3
goto humanFighter

:humanfighter1
set lvl1=1
set exp1=0
set expmax1=300
set gp1=10
set hp1=12
set ac1=15
set profbonus1=2
set str1=4
set dex1=1
set con1=2
set int1=0
set wis1=2
set cha1=2
cls
echo.
echo To find your stats open your character sheet labeled humanfighter1_cs.txt
echo.
echo What's your name?
echo.
set /p name1=Enter:
goto hf1main

:hf1main
cls
echo.
echo %name1% Human Fighter
echo Lvl: %lvl1% Money:%gp1%
echo Hit Points: %hp1%/12
echo Armor: Breastplate Armor Class: %ac1%
echo Exp: %exp1%/%expmax1%
echo Weapon: Battleaxe 1D8 Slashing
echo Stat Modifiers:
echo Strength: +%str1%
echo Dexterity: +%dex1%
echo Constitution: +%con1%
echo Intelligence: +%int1%
echo Wisdom: +%wis1%
echo Charisma: +%cha1%
echo -------------------------------------
echo 1) Continue
echo 2) Exit
echo.
set /p input=Enter:
if %input%==1 goto hf1continue
if %input%==2 exit
```

I expect it to create the batch file after creating an account so that you can log in later.

Comment: consider using [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /p input=Choice:`. It's a lot easier to handle because it only accepts defined inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For your menus, I would like to introduce you to `choice.exe` as an alternative to `Set /P`. It is far better to use it when input must be any one of a small set of known values. `Set /P` allows the end user to enter nothing or anything, and in order to maintain control you need to build in some input verification mechanism. *To find out how `choice.exe` works, open a `cmd.exe` window and enter `choice /?` at the prompt.*

Here is a rewritten example snippet of your script, *(lines `1`-`43`)* to hopefully explain why:

```
@Echo Off
Title Lost Mine of Phandelvor

:EnterGame
ClS
Echo(
Echo Welcome to Lost Mine of Phandelvor
Echo ----------------------------------
Echo(
Echo 1. Create Account
Echo 2. Login
Echo 3. Exit
Echo(
Choice /C 123
If ErrorLevel 3 Exit /B
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Login

:CreateUser
ClS
Echo(
Set "username1="
Set /P "username1=What would you like your Username to be? "
If Not Defined username1 GoTo CreateUser

:CheckForSpaces
If Not "%username1: =%"=="%username1%" (
    Echo Sorry you can not use spaces in your Username.
    Choice /M "Is %username1: =%" okay"
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo CreateUser
)
If Exist "%username1%.bat" GoTo :Login
Echo(
Set "password1="
Set /P "password1=What would you like your Password to be? "
```

However, before you continue with your script, based upon what I said about using `Set /P`. The end user can currently enter anything they want as `username1`. We've already checked for no entry and for spaces, but you're also saving the name as a filename too, `%name%.bat`. Along with the decimal character codes `0` through `31`, Windows filenames cannot contain any of the following characters, **<kbd>\</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd>**, so you'd need to incorporate further verification of `username1`. This verification procedure would need to be implemented before line `31` of the code above.

Before you do so however, you may want to consider changing your methodology and not saving the Username to the name of a file. The reason for this is that you'd also be wise not to use filenames ending with a **<kbd>.</kbd>**, or any named `CON`, `PRN`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1`, `COM2`, `COM3`, `COM4`, `COM5`, `COM6`, `COM7`, `COM8`, `COM9`, `LPT1`, `LPT2`, `LPT3`, `LPT4`, `LPT5`, `LPT6`, `LPT7`, `LPT8`, and `LPT9` either. So you would further need to include those verification checks of the input too.

Don't forget, you'll probably want to include a verification method for input entries to the `%password1%` prompt too!

Given the complexity involved with user input and `Set /P` you can see why I have recommended  `choice.exe` as a control measure for your menus.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh - so many errors!

First, add an extra line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` directly after the `@echo off` line. This has two effects - first, when your batch ends, your environment is restored to its original condition so that you don't get confused with variables that have been established by prior runs. second, it turns on `delayed expansion` mode - which is where the `!variable!` syntax you are using is activated, otherwise `!` is simply an ordinary character.

Next, having accepted input from the ketboard with a `set /p`, you have no idea whether the user entered. In your validation `if` statements, use `if "%var%"=="value"` which overcomes most input problems.

Next, the syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

And a little tip for games that need a save/restore feature:
If you reserve a character as a prefix for variables-you-want-to-save (eg all variables I want to save/reload start with `#`) then all you need to *save* a game is

```
set #>"mygamefile.txt"
```

and all you need to *reload* a game is

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("mygamefile.txt") do set "%%a"
```

To zap all `#` variables (useful before reloading a game) use

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
```

You should look at the thousands of code examples here on SO to find out how to use subroutines - you appear to be using "spaghetti code".

This code may help with your password-checking:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (passwordfilename) do if "%%a"=="%playername%" set "playerpass=%%b"
if "%playerpass%"=="%enteredpass%" goto gameon
```

This uses a single password file of the form

```
player1 password1
player2 password2
```

If `player1` changes password, then append the new data to the file like this:

```
player1 password1
player2 password2
player1 newpassword
```

and the above `for /f` construct will then set `playerpass` to the *last* occurrence of `player1` found.

This should provide you with a start and obviate your need for a subsidiary batch file. You'll have enough on your plate implementing these suggestions, but you should be able then to see the wood for the trees.

And implement changes one at a time, then test and debug them. Small steps will make the process a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same thing in my game. You need 2 functions, 1 to load and 1 to save. The save function should look something like this:

```
:: My save thing
:save
(
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
) > save.sav
```

and the loading portion should look something like this:

```
< save.sav (
set /p var1=
set /p var2=
)
```

also, one major recommendation, put all your scripts into separate files and folders. Like a normal game, example:

```
- MainGame
  - Launcher.bat
  - Resources
    - Scripts
      - Save.bat
      - Load.bat
      - Fight.bat
    - Assets
      - Title.txt
```

this is a similar structure to what I used in my game.